# ln command creates broken links

Tags: bash, makefile, dynamic-linking

I'm having trouble using the ln command in a makefile.

This is a part of my makefile for creating a dynamic library:

```
NAME := Net    
DDIR := dynamic_library    
DLIB := $(DDIR)/lib$(NAME).so    
MAJOR := 1    
MINOR := 0    
VERSION := $(MAJOR).$(MINOR)
$(DLIB).$(VERSION): $(OBJD)
    g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,$(DLIB).$(MAJOR) $^ -o $@
$(DLIB): $(DLIB).$(VERSION)
    ln -sf $(DLIB).$(VERSION) $(DLIB)
    ln -sf $(DLIB).$(VERSION) $(DLIB).$(MAJOR)
```

`OBJD` are my .o files.

I'm trying to create the links next to libNet.so.1.0 which is in dynamic_library/ .

The ln commands create broken links with incomplete target addresses but in the correct destination.

I've tried adding `./` and `/` before the sources but they don't work.

Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**
found the answer through trial and error

apparently we're supposed to add `../` before the sources. I have no idea why though.

if anybody has a better way, please answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the variations of `ln` command are:

```
ln -s abs_path_to_link_target rel_path_from_current_dir_to_link_source
ln -s rel_path_from_link_src_to_target rel_path_from_current_dir_to_link_source
```

But the following, which you were trying to use, is not one of them:

```
ln -s rel_path_from_current_dir_to_link_target ...
```

Your makefile has another subtle error, namely, the link source, does not depend on the changes to the link target, it only depends on the *existence* of the link target.

And another problem, is that you have a "side effect", when you are making `$(DLIB)` target.  I am guessing you are a software eng, so you know that side effects are bad for parallelism, cause race conditions, and make code hard to read.

Also, one should always use automatic variables such as `$@`, and depend everything on the Makefile.

Finally, I am hoping that you know why you are using `-f`.  Some of the responses above, including mine :), do not use it. It is very important in the Makefile context, don't drop it.

Bearing these points in mind, the cleanest and correct way to do this would be:

```
$(DLIB) $(DLIB).$(MAJOR): Makefile | $(DLIB).$(VERSION)
    ln -sf $(abspath $|) $@
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. This was my first attempt at making a proper makefile and  and i'm still trying to grasp the basics as I really have no idea what i'm doing.

Comment: @user3048908 you are well on your way.  At least, you are using the proper :=   I put some beginner pointers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816058/makefile-fibonacci

Answer (score 0):

```
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,$(DLIB).$(MAJOR) $^ -o $@
```

Isn't it supposed to be `-Wl,-soname,$(DLIB).$(VERSION)`?

Comment: No it works fine now that I added ../ before the sources. thanks.

Comment: it may 'work' for you, but it wouldn't if you'll rename directory to something other than 'dynamic_library'.

Answer (score 0):

`ln -s` creates a link at the destination location with a link target of your source path (not the full path the path you give the ln command). If your link destination is a directory below your source directory and you aren't using full paths to the source then you need the `../` so that the link target is `../source.file` instead of `source.file` as that would make the link point to a file in the same directory.

Compare:

```
$ ln -s bar foo
$ readlink foo
bar
$ readlink -f foo
/tmp/bar
$ ln -s ../bar foo
$ readlink foo
../bar
$ readlink -f foo
/foo
$ ln -s /tmp/bar foo
$ readlink foo
/tmp/bar
$ readlink -f foo
/tmp/bar
```